# EscapeSingleQuotes vf page button

Tags: visualforce, escape

I have a button that when clicked triggers actions in the controller. Which among other things triggers a query.

My text has a single quote in it such as " Dan's Product " In the query I used escapeSingleQuote method to convert the string. However, I think to escape the value before it gets to the controller because inspecting the button in chrome shows the ' and I think that's why the button doesn't work.

In my vf page I have this snippit:

```
<input class="btn" type="button" value="Add" onclick="addIntoSelectedProductAF('{!productBundle.Product_Identifier__c}', document.getElementById('selectRetailer').value
```

Which renders as:
 [image]

If I change the snippt to this:

```
input class="btn" type="button" value="Add" onclick="addIntoSelectedProductAF('String.escapeSingleQuote({!productBundle.Product_Identifier__c})', document.getElementById('selectRetailer').value
```

Which renders as:
[image]

Is there a way to have the merge field pull in the text and then escape the value to pass in the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visualforce, use JSINHTMLENCODE:

```
<input class="btn" type="button" value="Add" 
       onclick="addIntoSelectedProductAF('{!JSINHTMLESCAPE(productBundle.Product_Identifier__c)}', document.getElementById('selectRetailer').value)" />
```